# PDF Not Generated With Android WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, coldfusion-9

I've developed an application using ColdFusion 9.0. Then I converted the app to android app using WebView. There is is process where I used  to generate the PDF document and attach to Email using  and  tags.

**My CF Code:**

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="Alert">
<cfoutput query="getProdData" group="LineName">
<cfdocumentitem type="header">
<font size="-1"><i>Production Report - #dateFormat(ListFirst(form.prodDate),"dd-mm-yyyy")#</i></font>
<font size="-1"><i>From #ListFirst(form.fromTime)# To #ListFirst(form.toTime)#</i></font>
</cfdocumentitem>
<cfdocumentitem type="footer">
<font size="-1">Page #cfdocument.currentpagenumber#</font>
</cfdocumentitem>

<!--- Some Code --->
</cfdocument>

<cfmail to="email@somesite.com" 
bcc="email@somesite.com"
from="email@somesite.com"  
subject="Alert Message - Production Less Than 40%">
<cfmailparam file="Alert.pdf" content="#Alert#">  
Mail Body
</cfmail>
```

**My MainActivity.Java Code**

```
package com.example.rms;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet Connection.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://IPADDRESS:8500/RescrMobile/");
        }
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I Do not want to view the PDF. Just generate the PDF using the CF code and send the mail as attachment. But, unfortunately its not happening. I've tested it by sending an email without Generated PDF attachment and attached some static file, the EMAIL is sent. So I think the issue is with the ,  and  are working fine.

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: You have to save the PDF somehow in your android terminal, and send it as attachment file with the email. If this is your intention.

Comment: its posible show the pdf in a browser?

Comment: @ Massimo Pavanel If you look into <CFMAILPARAM>, the  <CFDOCUMENT> generates the PDF and programmatically attaches it as a file. This is working when the application is used as a web app. The <CFDOCUMENT> is some how not producing the PDF file when executed as a Mobile App.